# javascript check whether an element contains certain string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to search http links in images. If the image link contains a certain string in it, I want to check the checkbox associated with it:

I tried the following code but it does not work.

Here in the code below, I am trying to check the checkbox of the image if the image link contains the string "google".

How can I do that?

Thanks

```
for (i=0; i<document.getElementsByTagName('div').length; i++) 
  {

    if(document.getElementsByTagName('img')[i].evaluate(contains(@src, 'google'))
    {

        if(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i].type=='checkbox')
        {
        document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i].checked =true;
        }
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To search a specific substring inside a string you can use indexOf or a RegExp. E.g.:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[i].getAttribute("src").indexOf("google") > -1
```

Comment: thanks friend, it worked. It tells me that I need to wait 9more minutes in order to accept your answer. I will be doing that for sure!